How to track TTS progress in a Slider with Jetpack Compose?
Before Compose I had an Android TTS manager that tracked the progress of large amounts of text. And I used a SeekBar to mark the reading progress. Now I want to change the SeekBar for a Slider to mark the reading progress, but I can't get it to work. I don't know how to connect the TTS reading progress with a Slider.
This is the code of my TTS Manager;
class TtsManagerCompose(
    context: Context,
    text: String,
    splitRegex: String,
    private val mProgressListener: (Int, Int) -> Unit

)  : OnInitListener {
    private val mTexts: Array<String>
    private val mTts: TextToSpeech
    private var mTextProgress = 0
    private var mIsPlaying = false

    init {
        mTexts = text.split(splitRegex.toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
        mTts = TextToSpeech(context, this)
        mTts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(object : UtteranceProgressListener() {
            override fun onDone(utteranceId: String) {
                if (!mIsPlaying || mTextProgress == mTexts.size) return
                ++mTextProgress
                updateProgress(mTextProgress, mTexts.size)
                speakText()
            }

            override fun onStart(utteranceId: String) {}

            @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
            override fun onError(utteranceId: String) {
                //onError(utteranceId);
            }
        })
    }

    private fun speakText() {
        if (mTextProgress >= mTexts.size) return
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putInt(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
        mTts.speak(mTexts[mTextProgress], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, bundle, "TTS_ID")
    }

    fun start() {
        mIsPlaying = true
        speakText()
    }

    fun pause() {
        mIsPlaying = false
        mTts.stop()
        updateProgress(mTextProgress, mTexts.size)
    }

    fun resume() {
        mIsPlaying = false
        mTts.stop()
        start()
        updateProgress(mTextProgress, mTexts.size)
    }

    fun stop() {
        mIsPlaying = false
        mTts.stop()
        mTextProgress = 0
        updateProgress(mTextProgress, mTexts.size)
    }

    private fun updateProgress(current: Int, max: Int) {
        mProgressListener.invoke(current, max)
    }

    fun changeProgress(progress: Int) {
        mTextProgress = progress
        if (!mIsPlaying) return
        pause()
        start()
    }

    override fun onInit(status: Int) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            val locSpanish = Locale("spa", "ESP")
            val result = mTts.setLanguage(locSpanish)
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                return
            }
            changeProgress(1)
        }
    }

    fun close() {
        mTts.stop()
        mTts.shutdown()
    }
}


This is the code for the screen:
private var mTtsManager: TtsManagerCompose? = null

@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@Composable
fun TextToSpeechScreen(text:String,) {
    var readText by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(24.dp)) {
        isSpeaking = false
        SliderMinimalExample()

        if(readText){
            readText(text = text)
        }
        
        Button(onClick = {
            readText=true
        }) {
            Image(
                painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_play),
                contentDescription ="Play",
                modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp))
        }

        Button(onClick = {
            mTtsManager?.stop()
            readText=false
        }) {
            Image(
                painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_stop_circle_24),
                contentDescription ="Stop",
                modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp)) }
    }
    
    //TODO: Buttons for Pause / Resume ...
}

And this is the code for read the text:
@Composable
private fun readText(text:String) {
    mTtsManager = TtsManagerCompose(
        LocalContext.current, text,
        Constants.SEPARADOR,
    ) { current: Int, max: Int ->
//        seekBar!!.progress = current
//        seekBar!!.max = max
    }
    mTtsManager!!.start()
}

This is the code for SliderMinimalExample:
@Composable
fun SliderMinimalExample() {
    var sliderPosition by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
    Column {
        Slider(
            value = sliderPosition,
            onValueChange = { sliderPosition = it }
        )
        Text(text = sliderPosition.toString())
    }
}

Edit: New version of code
The TTS is working, but the progress is not tracked into the Slider, it remains fixed.
TextToSpeechScreen
private var mTtsManager: TtsManagerCompose? = null

@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@Composable
fun TextToSpeechScreen(text: StringBuilder) {
    var isSpeaking by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var sliderValue by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var sliderMaxValue by remember { mutableStateOf(100f) }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(24.dp)) {
        //isSpeaking = false
        SliderMinimalExample(sliderValue, sliderMaxValue)
        if (isSpeaking) {
            readText(text = text)
        }

        Button(onClick = {
            isSpeaking = true

        }) {
            Image(
                painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_play),
                contentDescription = "Play",
                modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp)
            )

        }

        Button(onClick = {
            mTtsManager?.stop()
            isSpeaking = false
        }) {
            Image(
                painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_stop_circle_24),
                contentDescription = "Stop",
                modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp)
            )
        }
        //TODO: Buttons for Pause / Resume ...
    }
}


SliderMinimalExample
@Composable
fun SliderMinimalExample(
    sliderValue: Float,
    sliderMaxValue: Float
) {
    var sliderPosition by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
    Column {
        Slider(
            //value = sliderPosition,
            value = sliderValue,
            valueRange = 0f..sliderMaxValue,
            onValueChange = { sliderPosition = it }
        )
        Text(text = sliderPosition.toString())
    }
}


readText method
@Composable
private fun readText(text: StringBuilder) {
    var sliderValue by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
    var sliderMaxValue by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(100f) }
    mTtsManager = TtsManagerCompose(
        LocalContext.current, text,
        Constants.SEPARADOR,
    ) {  current: Int,max: Int ->
        sliderValue = current.toFloat() // Update current value
        sliderMaxValue = max.toFloat() // Update Max alue
    }
    mTtsManager!!.start()
}


TtsManagerCompose class
class TtsManagerCompose(
    context: Context,
    text: StringBuilder,
    splitRegex: String,
    private var mProgressListener: (Int, Int) -> Unit

) : OnInitListener {
    private val mTexts: Array<String>
    private val mTts: TextToSpeech
    private var mTextProgress = 0
    private var mIsPlaying = false
    var sliderValue by mutableStateOf(0f)
    var sliderMaxValue by mutableStateOf(100f)

    init {
        mTexts = text.split(splitRegex.toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
        mTts = TextToSpeech(context, this)
        mTts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(object : UtteranceProgressListener() {
            override fun onDone(utteranceId: String) {
                if (!mIsPlaying || mTextProgress == mTexts.size) return
                ++mTextProgress
                updateProgress(sliderValue.toInt(), mTexts.size)
                speakText()
            }

            override fun onStart(utteranceId: String) {}

            @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
            override fun onError(utteranceId: String) {
                //onError(utteranceId);
            }
        })
    }

    private fun speakText() {
        if (mTextProgress >= mTexts.size) return
        //API 21+
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putInt(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
        mTts.speak(mTexts[mTextProgress], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, bundle, "TTS_ID")
    }



    fun start() {
        mIsPlaying = true
        speakText()
    }

    fun pause() {
        mIsPlaying = false
        mTts.stop()
        updateProgress(mTextProgress, mTexts.size)
    }

    fun resume() {
        mIsPlaying = false
        mTts.stop()
        start()
        updateProgress(mTextProgress, mTexts.size)
    }

    fun stop() {
        mIsPlaying = false
        mTts.stop()
        mTextProgress = 0
        updateProgress(mTextProgress, mTexts.size)
    }

    private fun updateProgress(current: Int, max: Int) {
        mProgressListener.invoke(current, max)
    }

    fun changeProgress(progress: Int) {
        mTextProgress = progress
        if (!mIsPlaying) return
        pause()
        start()
    }

    override fun onInit(status: Int) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            val locSpanish = Locale("spa", "ESP")
            val result = mTts.setLanguage(locSpanish)
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                return
            }
            changeProgress(1)
        }
    }

    fun close() {
        mTts.stop()
        mTts.shutdown()
    }
}


Can you post the code of your SliderMinimalExample composable as well?

@gtxtreme I added the code for SliderMinimalExample.

Okay, so first of all, you should definitely read Thinking in Compose so that you understand the difference between Declarative and Imperative Programming
Next, coming to your solution it's pretty easy I'd say
First, let's make a state for your Slider in your TTSManagerCompose

class TTSCompose{

  var sliderValue by mutableStateOf(0f)
  var sliderMaxValue by mutableStateOf(100f)

  //..Other code
}

Once that's done, let's update the value of this slider, in the readText method. Additionally using valueRange to restrict the Slider to the Max Value
@Composable
private fun readText(text:String) {
    mTtsManager = TtsManagerCompose(
        LocalContext.current, text,
        Constants.SEPARADOR,
    ) { current: Int, max: Int ->
      sliderValue = current // Update current value
      sliderMaxValue = max // Update Max alue
    }
    mTtsManager!!.start()
}

Now, send these to your SliderMinimalExample like so
Adding valueRange to restrict the max value
@Composable
fun SliderMinimalExample(sliderValue: MutableState<Float>,
                         sliderMaxValue: MutableState<Float>
) {
    Column {
        Slider(
            value = sliderValue.value,
            onValueChange = { sliderPosition = it },
            valueRange = 0f..sliderMaxValue.value
        )
        Text(text = sliderPosition.toString())
    }
}

You can customise more paramters of the Slider composable, by reading the docs here

Thank you for your answer. I can't get it to work, I can't find what I'm doing wrong. I've put the current state of the code in a final edit in the question. Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
